# useParams hook returns undefined in react functional component

Tags: reactjs, url, parameters, react-hooks, router

The app displays all photos `<Photo>` in a grid `<PhotoGrid>`, then once clicked, a function in `<Photo>` changes URL with `history.push`, and Router renders `<Single>` based on URL using `useParams` hook.

`PhotoGrid` -> `Photo` (changes URL onClick) -> `Single` based on URL (useParams).
I must have messed something up, becouse useParams returns undefined.

Thanks for all ideas in advanced.
App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={PhotoGrid}/>
          <Route path="/view/:postId" component={Single}/>
        </Switch>
      </>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

Photogrid.js

```
export default function PhotoGrid() {
    const posts = useSelector(selectPosts);

    return (
        <div>
            hi
            {/* {console.log(posts)} */}
            {posts.map((post, i) => <Photo key={i} i={i} post={post} />)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

in Photo I change URL with history.push

```
const selectPost = () => {
  (...)
  history.push(`/view/${post.code}`);
  };
```

Single.js

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
export default function Single() {
    let { id } = useParams();
    console.log("id:",  id)   //returns undefined

    return (
      <div className="single-photo">
       the id is: {id} //renders nothing
      </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When using useParams, you have to match the destructure `let { postId } = useParams();` to your path `"/view/:postId"`.

Working Single.js

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Single() {
    const { postId } = useParams();
    console.log("this.context:",  postId )

    return (
      <div className="single-photo">
        {/* render something based on postId */}
      </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: You should definitely use `const` instead of `let`.  Destructure the param value -> `const { postId } = useParams()`

Comment: I'm saddened that I had to end up here to work that out given that I have already done it a hundred time in the code already. But thanks anyway.

Comment: thanks!! i had the same issue and solved it completely

Answer (score 4):

You should use the same destructure as mentioned in your Route path. In this case, you should have written :

```js
let { postID } = useParams();
```

I will mention two more mistakes which someone could make and face the same problem:

1. You might use Router component in place of Route component.
2. You might forget to mention the parameter in the path attribute of the Route component, while you would have mentioned it in the Link to component.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure the component where you call `useParams()` is really a child from `<Route>`

Beware of `ReactDOM.createPortal`

```
const App = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={PhotoGrid}/>
          <Route path="/view/:postId" component={Single}/>
        </Switch>
       <ComponentCreateWithPortal /> // Impossible to call it there
      </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to check API that you are using. Sometimes it's called not just id. That's why useParams() do not see it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).