# TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined in Details page - Basic CRUD app in React / Express

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Having trouble with what seems to be a pretty common React problem. Gettting **TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined** in a very basic CRUD application. I'm navigating directly to http://localhost/microjobs/[id] (where [id] is specified), and getting this error.

App.jsx calls
views/Microjob.jsx, which calls
components/MicrojobContainer.

But for some reason the Microjob Container can't see the URL. Any thoughts why? Following this tutorial, FYI: https://www.bezkoder.com/react-crud-web-api/, but using the React app from scaffold-eth. The API/Database is working fine.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

From **app.jsx:**

```
        <BrowserRouter>

          <Menu style={{ textAlign:"center" }} selectedKeys={[route]} mode="horizontal">
            <Menu.Item key="/">
              <Link onClick={()=>{setRoute("/")}} to="/">Home</Link>
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="/new">
              <Link onClick={()=>{setRoute("/new")}} to="/new">New Job</Link>
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="/microjobs/:id">
              <Link onClick={()=>{setRoute("/microjobs/:id")}} to="/microjobs/:id">View</Link>
            </Menu.Item>
          </Menu>

          <Switch>
            <Route exact path={["/", "/microjobs"]} component={MicrojobList} />
            <Route path="/new" component={NewJob} /> 
            <Route path="/microjobs/:id" component={Microjob} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

In **views/microjob.jsx**:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { formatEther } from "@ethersproject/units";
import { Address, AddressInput, MicrojobContainer } from "../components";

export default function Microjob() {
  let {microjobId} = useParams();

  return (
    <div>
      <MicrojobContainer id={microjobId} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

In **components/MicrojobContainer.jsx**:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import MicrojobDataService from "../services/microjob.service";

export default class MicrojobContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onChangeTitle = this.onChangeTitle.bind(this);
    this.onChangeDescription = this.onChangeDescription.bind(this);
    this.getMicrojob = this.getMicrojob.bind(this);
    this.updatePublished = this.updatePublished.bind(this);
    this.updateMicrojob = this.updateMicrojob.bind(this);
    this.deleteMicrojob = this.deleteMicrojob.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      currentMicrojob: {
        id: null,
        title: "",
        description: "",
        published: false
      },
      message: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
// THIS LINE IS WHERE THE ERROR IS - this.props.match.params.id is undefined
    this.getMicrojob(this.props.match.params.id);
  }



  getMicrojob(id) {
    MicrojobDataService.get(id)
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          currentMicrojob: response.data
        });
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Looks like there is no prop called match. Looks like `Microjob` is already responsible for pulling the `microjobId` from the URL and passing it to `MicrojobContainer` as `id`. Assuming that is working you can just use `this.props.id`.

Comment: @RyanJackman they are grabbing `id` from react-router route params

Comment: @RyanJackman I was very optimistic but unfortunately this didn't work - this.props.id is not throwing an error but it actually doesn't contain the ID - it's still undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this incase anyone is looking - thanks to this post: [useParams hook returns undefined in react functional component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66506891/useparams-hook-returns-undefined-in-react-functional-component).

It turns out the variable name used when calling `useParams` needs to be the same used in the `<Route />`. In my case, my `Route` was:

```
<Route path="/microjobs/:id" component={Microjob} />
```

And when I called `useParams()`:

```
let {microjobId} = useParams();
```

As soon as I changed to use `id` instead of `microjobId`, everything worked fine and useParams returned the ID from the URL.